# Import of jakarta.validation missing

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm following and online course on Springboot MVC. I'm working with Springboot 3.1.0-M1 version, java 17 and Eclipse 2022-09.
Now the course tells me to use the annotation @Valid in the file UserResource.java for the validation of the input.
This annotation should import the library
`import jakarta.validation.Valid` but Eclipse does not give me this possibility: the library of jakarta.validation is not in list that Eclipse propones me. Morover, if i try to add manually that libray (`jakarta.validation.*`), Eclipse underlines that code line in red and tells me that `The import jakarta.validation cannot be resolved`.
the @Valid annotation return me the following message: `Valid cannot be resolved to a type`.
I tried to import the library `javax.validation.Valid` without results.
If i write `jakarta.` in Eclipse for import a libray, the system return me a lot of libraries (ie: jakarta.ammotation, jakarta.servlet) but not the validation library.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <parent>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
     <version>3.1.0-M1</version>
     <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent>
 <groupId>com.in28minutes.rest.webservices</groupId>
 <artifactId>restful-web-services</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <name>restful-web-services</name>
 <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
 <properties>
     <java.version>17</java.version>
 </properties>
 <dependencies>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
     </dependency>

     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
     </dependency>
     
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
         <scope>runtime</scope>
         <optional>true</optional>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
         <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
         <scope>runtime</scope>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
         <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>
 </dependencies>

 <build>
     <plugins>
         <plugin>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         </plugin>
     </plugins>
 </build>
 <repositories>
     <repository>
         <id>spring-milestones</id>
         <name>Spring Milestones</name>
         <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
         <snapshots>
             <enabled>false</enabled>
         </snapshots>
     </repository>
 </repositories>
 <pluginRepositories>
     <pluginRepository>
         <id>spring-milestones</id>
         <name>Spring Milestones</name>
         <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
         <snapshots>
             <enabled>false</enabled>
         </snapshots>
     </pluginRepository>
 </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

UserResouce.java

```
package com.in28minutes.rest.webservices.restfulwebservices.user;

import java.net.URI;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder;

import javax.validation.*;

@RestController
public class UserResource {
    
    private UserDaoService service;
    
    public UserResource(UserDaoService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @GetMapping("/users")
    public List<User> retriveAllUsers() {
        return service.findAll();
    }
     
    @GetMapping("/users/{id}")
    public User retriveUser(@PathVariable int id) {
        User user = service.findOne(id);
        
        if (user==null)
            throw new UserNotFoundException("id:"+id);
        
        return user;
    }
    
    @DeleteMapping("/users/{id}")
    public void deleteUser(@PathVariable int id) {
        service.deleteById(id);
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/users")
    public ResponseEntity<User> createUser(@Valid @RequestBody User user) {
        User savedUser = service.save(user);
        URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/{id}").buildAndExpand(savedUser.getId()).toUri();
        return ResponseEntity.created(location).build();
    }
}
```

What am I wronging?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried adding this dependency in pom
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>

Comment: For starters I would suggest using 3.1.1 as the version instead of some old milestone release and as you are using Eclipse make sure it is properly refreshed and you have imported your project as a Maven one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have this dependency `spring-boot-starter-validation` so it should work, try good old restart of eclipse and make sure maven did pull the dependency

Comment: Why would that bring in `jakarta.validation.*`? The maven central description for spring-boot-starter-validation is _"Starter for using Java Bean Validation with Hibernate Validaton"_

Comment: hibernate validator is built on top of jakarta validation api specification.

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```